# Where is the man page for scaladoc?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Looking at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/scaladoc.html there are examples for giving scaladoc options such `-groups` and `-implicits`.

Where is the information regarding the scaladoc (2.10) options? Like a man page. I can't seem to find it, neither of docs.scala-lang.org, nor on wiki.scala-lang.org...

I don't use a Scala installation besides managed by sbt, so I really would like an online resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`scaladoc -help` gives:

```
Usage: scaladoc <options> <source files>
where possible scaladoc options include:
  -diagrams                                   Create inheritance diagrams for classes, traits and packages.
  -diagrams-dot-path <path>                   The path to the dot executable used to generate the inheritance diagrams. Eg: /usr/bin/dot
  -diagrams-dot-restart <n>                   The number of times to restart a malfunctioning dot process before disabling diagrams (default: 5)
  -diagrams-dot-timeout <n>                   The timeout before the graphviz dot util is forcefully closed, in seconds (default: 10)
  -diagrams-max-classes <n>                   The maximum number of superclasses or subclasses to show in a diagram
  -diagrams-max-implicits <n>                 The maximum number of implicitly converted classes to show in a diagram
  -doc-footer <footer>                        A footer on every ScalaDoc page, by default the EPFL/Typesafe copyright notice. Can be overridden with a custom footer.
  -doc-format:<format>                        Selects in which format documentation is rendered (html) default:html
  -doc-generator <class-name>                 The fully qualified name of a doclet class, which will be used to generate the documentation
  -doc-no-compile <path>                      A directory containing sources which should be parsed, no more (e.g. AnyRef.scala)
  -doc-root-content <path>                    The file from which the root package documentation should be imported.
  -doc-source-url <url>                       A URL pattern used to build links to template sources; use variables, for example: ?{TPL_NAME} ('Seq'), ?{TPL_OWNER} ('scala.collection'), ?{FILE_PATH} ('scala/collection/Seq')
  -doc-title <title>                          The overall name of the Scaladoc site
  -doc-version <version>                      An optional version number, to be appended to the title
  -expand-all-types                           Expand all type aliases and abstract types into full template pages. (locally this can be done with the @template annotation)
  -groups                                     Group similar functions together (based on the @group annotation)
  -implicits                                  Document members inherited by implicit conversions.
  -implicits-hide:<implicit(s)>               Hide the members inherited by the given comma separated, fully qualified implicit conversions. Add dot (.) to include default conversions.
  -implicits-show-all                         Show members inherited by implicit conversions that are impossible in the default scope. (for example conversions that require Numeric[String] to be in scope)
  -no-link-warnings                           Avoid warnings for ambiguous and incorrect links.
  -no-prefixes                                Prevents generating prefixes in types, possibly creating ambiguous references, but significantly speeding up scaladoc.
  -raw-output                                 For each html file, create another .html.raw file containing only the text. (can be used for quickly diffing two scaladoc outputs)
  -skip-packages <<package1>:...:<packageN>>  A colon-delimited list of fully qualified package names that will be skipped from scaladoc.

Additional debug settings:
  -diagrams-debug                             Show debugging information for the diagram creation process.
  -implicits-debug                            Show debugging information for members inherited by implicit conversions.

Standard scalac options also available:
  -Dproperty=value                  Pass -Dproperty=value directly to the runtime system.
  -J<flag>                          Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system.
  -P:<plugin>:<opt>                 Pass an option to a plugin
  -X                                Print a synopsis of advanced options.
  -bootclasspath <path>             Override location of bootstrap class files.
  -classpath <path>                 Specify where to find user class files.
  -d <directory|jar>                destination for generated classfiles.
  -dependencyfile <file>            Set dependency tracking file.
  -deprecation                      Emit warning and location for usages of deprecated APIs.
  -doc-external-doc:<external-doc>  comma-separated list of classpath_entry_path#doc_URL pairs describing external dependencies.
  -encoding <encoding>              Specify character encoding used by source files.
  -explaintypes                     Explain type errors in more detail.
  -extdirs <path>                   Override location of installed extensions.
  -external-urls:<externalUrl(s)>   (deprecated) comma-separated list of package_names=doc_URL for external dependencies, where package names are ':'-separated
  -feature                          Emit warning and location for usages of features that should be imported explicitly.
  -g:<level>                        Set level of generated debugging info. (none,source,line,vars,notailcalls) default:vars
  -help                             Print a synopsis of standard options
  -implicits-sound-shadowing        Use a sound implicit shadowing calculation. Note: this interacts badly with usecases, so only use it if you haven't defined usecase for implicitly inherited members.
  -javabootclasspath <path>         Override java boot classpath.
  -javaextdirs <path>               Override java extdirs classpath.
  -language:<feature>               Enable one or more language features.
  -no-specialization                Ignore @specialize annotations.
  -nobootcp                         Do not use the boot classpath for the scala jars.
  -nowarn                           Generate no warnings.
  -optimise                         Generates faster bytecode by applying optimisations to the program
  -print                            Print program with Scala-specific features removed.
  -sourcepath <path>                Specify location(s) of source files.
  -target:<target>                  Target platform for object files. All JVM 1.5 targets are deprecated. (jvm-1.5,jvm-1.5-fjbg,jvm-1.5-asm,jvm-1.6,jvm-1.7,msil) default:jvm-1.6
  -toolcp <path>                    Add to the runner classpath.
  -unchecked                        Enable additional warnings where generated code depends on assumptions.
  -uniqid                           Uniquely tag all identifiers in debugging output.
  -usejavacp                        Utilize the java.class.path in classpath resolution.
  -verbose                          Output messages about what the compiler is doing.
  -version                          Print product version and exit.
  @<file>                           A text file containing compiler arguments (options and source files)

Deprecated settings:
  -make:<policy>                    Recompilation detection policy (all,changed,immediate,transitive,transitivenocp) default:all
                                      deprecated: this option is unmaintained.  Use sbt or an IDE for selective recompilation.
```

Beside from that I don't know of any other information sites. The only thing available for sure is the source code that contains [all settings](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/nsc/doc/Settings.scala).